# Sublime Text 3 - Is there a autocompletion / dropdown list feature?

Tags: auto-completion, sublime-text

In Texmaker or TexStudio, one can begin to type and the program will display a dropdown menu of suggestions. Is there something similar to this in Sublime Text 3? If so, how do I enable it?

Comment: @HarishKumar Yes, but that is not a dropdown menu

Answer (score 5):

A bit late, but LaTeXTools just added this feature in the last two weeks. Basically as soon as you press `\`, start typing, it will pop up a list of suggestions. The (brief) docs on this feature [can be found here](https://github.com/SublimeText/LaTeXTools#latex-cwl-support).

[image: Screenshot showing cwl completions on LaTeXTools]

Comment: It is not working by default in `Sublime Text 3`. Could you please provide to us some wider explanation. I am missing this feature much.

Comment: @JanFilip: Make sure you installed the LaTeX-cwl package as well as LaTeXTools.

Comment: @JanFilip For me Latex-cwl was conflicting with "All AutoComplet" package. Removing All AutoComplete solves this.

Comment: Installing cwl package solved my problem.

Answer (score 4):

Depending on which LaTeX plug-in you're using, you can have a similar behaviour as you're requesting. For instance, [LaTeX-cwl](https://github.com/LaTeXing/LaTeX-cwl) in combination with the [LaTeXing](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/LaTeXing) plug-in, you'll get a behaviour like shown below. Note that if I'd written `\doc` I'd get another set of alternatives (obviously - `doteq` doesn't contain a c)

[image]

Comment: Is this possible w/ LaTeXTools?

Comment: No idea. Checkout the LaTeX-cwl documentation!